# How to get file names in archive with 7z

Tags: 7z

Using 7z, I'd like to print the names of the files inside an archive.

The output of `7z l myArchive.7z` is

```
7-Zip [64] 16.02 : Copyright (c) 1999-2016 Igor Pavlov : 2016-05-21
p7zip Version 16.02 (locale=en_US.utf8,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,64 bits,4 CPUs Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2520M CPU @ 2.50GHz (206A7),ASM,AES-NI)

Scanning the drive for archives:
1 file, 171329 bytes (168 KiB)

Listing archive: myArchive.7z

--
Path = myArchive.7z
Type = 7z
Physical Size = 171329
Headers Size = 237
Method = LZMA2:18
Solid = +
Blocks = 1

  Date      Time    Attr         Size   Compressed  Name
------------------- ----- ------------ ------------  ------------------------
2020-06-05 16:03:29 ....A            0            0  file with spaces
2020-06-05 11:53:13 ....A        96616       171092  screen_2020-06-05_11-53-13.png
2020-06-05 11:53:43 ....A       106932               screen_2020-06-05_11-53-43.png
------------------- ----- ------------ ------------  ------------------------
2020-06-05 16:03:29             203548       171092  3 files
```

I'd like to make 7z print only the file names:

```
file with spaces
screen_2020-06-05_11-53-13.png
screen_2020-06-05_11-53-43.png
```

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use libarchive's `bsdtar`:

```
bsdtar tf file.7z
```

Also note that `7z l` would prompt you for a password if the archive is encrypted while `bsdtar` will just return with an error which would be preferable in scripts.

Comment: `tar` on Cygwin

Answer (score 2):

## With `-slt`

This command

```
7z -slt l myArchive.7z | grep -oP "(?<=Path = ).+" | tail -n +2
```

prints

```
file with spaces
screen_2020-06-05_11-53-13.png
screen_2020-06-05_11-53-43.png
```

The `-slt` option "[s]ets technical mode for l (list) command", according to the [manual](https://linux.die.net/man/1/7z).

This option makes 7z print information about the files of the archive in a parsable way.

Here's the output of `7z -slt l myArchive.7z`:

```
Listing archive: file with spaces.7z

--
Path = file with spaces.7z
Type = 7z
Physical Size = 171329
Headers Size = 237
Method = LZMA2:18
Solid = +
Blocks = 1

----------
Path = file with spaces
Size = 0
Packed Size = 0
Modified = 2020-06-05 16:03:29
Attributes = A_ -rw-r--r--
CRC = 
Encrypted = -
Method = 
Block = 

Path = screen_2020-06-05_11-53-13.png
Size = 96616
Packed Size = 171092
Modified = 2020-06-05 11:53:13
Attributes = A_ -rw-r--r--
CRC = 41911DBA
Encrypted = -
Method = LZMA2:18
Block = 0

Path = screen_2020-06-05_11-53-43.png
Size = 106932
Packed Size = 
Modified = 2020-06-05 11:53:43
Attributes = A_ -rw-r--r--
CRC = B0ECEA85
Encrypted = -
Method = LZMA2:18
Block = 0
```

The grep part of the command `| grep -oP "(?<=^Path = ).+"` warrants explanation:

- `-o`: grep only prints the matched string, not the whole line.
- `P`: enable [Perl compatible regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Compatible_Regular_Expressions) in grep. We need this for the lookbehind in the regex.
- `(?<=^Path = ).+"`: grep's regex. Get all characters after the line starting with "Path = ". The `(?<=` part is a [positive lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) which means the line has to start with "Path = ", but that string is not part of the match. The characters that come after are the matched string. Those characters are the file name.

After that, we have the archive name on the first line and all the file names below. We remove the first line with `| tail -n +2`.

Comment: +1 just because I am always amazed at what can be done with perl, but wouldn't `7z -slt l myArchive.7z | sed 's/Path = \(.*\)/\1/'` be more simple ? Just saying...

Comment: Thanks @Cbhihe. I modified your command to only print the file names: `7z -slt l myArchive.7z | sed -n 's/Path = \(.*\)/\1/p' | tail -n +2`